# Increase the size of derivative

Tags: fractions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
The vertical differential velocity is 

$\delta v_2 = v_{2C} - v_{2A} = v_2(x + \delta x , y) - v_2(x,y) \approx 
\delta x \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x} $. 
\end{document}
```

How can I make the derivative appears larger rather than having the same size as the words in the sentence?

Thanks!

Comment: `\displaystyle\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x}`, the key being `\displaystyle`.

Comment: If you're comfortable with inline-style fraction notation, write `(\partial v_2/\partial x)` instead of `frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x}`.

Comment: With `\dfrac` you get what you'd like, but you spoil the line spacing.

Comment: do you really want that expression to be _inline_  math?? (I would remove the blank line before the equation and then replace `$`...`$` by `\[...\]`

Answer (score 2):

Normally such a large expression should be set as a display math environment, not as a paragraph using inline math:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\section{inline}

The vertical differential velocity is 

$\delta v_2 = v_{2C} - v_{2A} = v_2(x + \delta x , y) - v_2(x,y) \approx 
\delta x \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x} $. 


\section{display}

The vertical differential velocity is 
\[\delta v_2 = v_{2C} - v_{2A} = v_2(x + \delta x , y) - v_2(x,y) \approx 
\delta x \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x} \mbox{.}\] 


\end{document}
```